# My script needs write access to /dev/sdX. How to avoid runnig it as root?

Tags: linux, root, non-root-user

I'm developing a Bash script that handles formatting and testing (with `f3`) of massive amounts of USB drives, like this:

```
mkntfs -QF /dev/sdX
```

I used to simply run that script as root:

```
sudo MyScript.sh
```

However today while reworking this tool to become modular I've managed to accidentally do something that blows my OS up every time I run this script. Various applications close or break, and I can't perform basic commandline tasks any more. Thankfully a reboot fixes everything, but that got me thinking again - maybe I *really* shouldn't run this script as root?

The problem is - I need to perform some actions that are restricted from normal users (like write access to device character files in /dev/).

What can I do to grant my script precise permissions and avoid the possibility that an unlucky typo will wipe my hard drive or destroy my `/dev/null`?

Comment: I take it sudo is not the answer?

Comment: That's what I do right now, and it's not safe and have just lead me to trouble.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a `udev` rule to match USB drives and make them writable by a group of your choice, and run the script in that group.

The following matches should identify removable USB drives:

```
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", ATTR{removable}=="1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Where should I put this rule? How can I make it assign to a group? How can I run my script as a group?